# calculus - Finding the global maximum and minimum points of this two variables function

Tags: calculus

$f(x, y) = 4-y$  in $D:=(x, y, z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2=8, x+y+z=1$

I used Lagrange for this function, but I got a bit confused after I solved the system of equations.

$\mathcal{L}(x, y, z, \lambda, \rho) = 4-y-\lambda(x^2+y^2-8) - \rho(x+y+z-1)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -2\lambda x-\rho $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -1-2\lambda y - \rho $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = -\rho$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda} = -x^2-y^2+8$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} = -x-y-z+1$

So I set up the following system of equations:

$\begin{cases} 2\lambda x = 0\\2\lambda y + 1=0 \\x^2+y^2-8 = 0\\x+y+z-1=0 \end{cases}$

At the end of the system, I get these solutions:

$\begin{cases} x=0 \\ \lambda = -\frac{1}{\pm4\sqrt{2}} \\ y = \pm2\sqrt{2} \\z=1\pm2\sqrt{2} \\ \rho = 0\end{cases}$

Now I have some doubts here. Since the function only has two variables, am I just supposed to ignore $\lambda$ and $\rho$?

If so, to find the global maximum and minimum, do I just plug $(0, -2\sqrt{2}) $ and $ (0, 2\sqrt{2}) $ into the function? Because in this case, I get that $f(0, -2\sqrt{2}) > f(0, 2\sqrt{2})$ meaning that $(0, -2\sqrt{2})$ is the global maximum, while the other point is the global minimum, right?

Comment: The variable $z$ in your function is missing!

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it now. It was f(x, y) and not f(x, y, z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable  to be consistent and view $f$ as $f(x,y,z)=4+0x-y+0z.$

Also, note that the problem that you are working with is compact.

$(0, -2\sqrt2, 1+2\sqrt2)$ is the global maximum and $(0, 2\sqrt2, 1-2\sqrt2)$ is the global minimum.

Your problem has equality constraint, there is no sign constraints imposed on the Langrangian variable. For inequality constraint, you have to make sure that sign constraint is satisfied as well.